# Clojure luminus framework how to call mongodb connect with mount

Tags: mongodb, clojure, ring, luminus

I started to develop using **Clojure luminus framework** with **mongodb** (with monger library).
It was very hard to understand how to implement `mount` library to start the db connection.

I figured out that code should put `handler.clj` 's `init` function.

But I cannot figure out how to tell mount to start the database connection.

Please could you give me a hand?

Here gores my development config.clj

```
    (ns vippro.config
  (:require [selmer.parser :as parser]
            [clojure.tools.logging :as log]
            [vippro.dev-middleware :refer [wrap-dev]]
))

(def defaults
  {:init
   (fn []
     (parser/cache-off!)
     (log/info "\n-=[vippro started successfully using the development profile]=-"))
   :middleware wrap-dev})
```

and in `handler.clj` 's `init` function

```
(defn init
  "init will be called once when
   app is deployed as a servlet on
   an app server such as Tomcat
   put any initialization code here"
  []
  (when-let [config (:log-config env)]
    (org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator/configure config))
  (doseq [component (:started (mount/start))]
    (log/info component "started"))
  ((:init defaults)))
```

my main problem is how should I call this function from `init` proper way

```
(defn connect! []
  ;; Tries to get the Mongo URI from the environment variable
  (reset! db (-> (:database-url env) mg/connect-via-uri :db)))
```

Comment: Please be more specific, if you provide your attempted implementation, we might be able to tell you where it went wrong.

Comment: @RicardoAcuna thanks. I added code what I think is relavent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original question was about how to use `mount` to do this.

It doesn't look like that's what you are doing, although your mongodb client is initializing, I suspect it is doing it when the namespace loads.

You defined a `connect!` function which connects and puts the value in an atom `db`. This is not the proper way to manage state with `mount` since you are using your own atom to store the state. Instead, try using `mount.core/defstate` to create and destroy the mongo client:

```clojure
(defstate settings
  :start {:mongo-uri "mongodb://localhost/my-database"})

(defn- mongo-connect
  [{:keys [mongo-uri]}]
  (mg/connect-via-uri mongo-uri))

(defn- mongo-disconnect
  [{:keys [conn] :as mongo-client}]
  (mg/disconnect conn))

(defstate mongo-client
  :start (mongo-connect settings)
  :stop (mongo-disconnect mongo-client))

(defn db [] (:db mongo-client))
```

By doing this you get the benefits of `mount`.

Then you could use `environ/env` as your `settings` and `export MONGO_URI="mongodb://..."`

Comment: Thanks. Those days I wasn't aware about this.

Answer (score 1):

The mongodb database started automatically when I set environment variable

```
export DATABASE_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1/dbname"
```

and then I started the ring server